What does integrity check mean?
I'm using a ABP2LANT001PG2A3XX Honeywell pressure sensor. I received 10 prototypes but only few of them work correctly. For most of the boards, the sensors is alive but the measured pressure floating around very much (i.e. at atmosferic pressure it quickly bouncing around from -80 to -250 Pa).
Inspecting the incoming data I noticed that after few second from power-up it returns a status byte = 0x65. Looking at the datasheet, I see the third bit is set:

2 (Memory integrity/error flag)
0 = integrity test passed
1 = integrity test failed
Indicates whether the checksum-based integrity check
passed or failed; the memory error status bit is calculated
only during the power-up sequence

I searched in the documentation for further information but I found nothing.
What does that mean?
Could be the sensor damaged? Or there is anything I could do via firmware to restore its correct behavior?

The implication is that the sensor contains a memory, and the integrity test is validating the contents of that memory. A failure of the test means that the contents of the memory have changed in an unintended way. The memory might contain code for an internal MCU, calibration data, etc.

@DaveTweed, ok but what can I do then?

Not a lot, based on the datasheet. If I knew, I would have written an answer rather than a comment. Perhaps the sensors were damaged through improper handling (ESD?) and are now toast.
